# EasyUI and JQuery-UI libraries conflict on Resize

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-easyui

I have a project where I need to use both EasyUI (Datagrid) and JQueryUI (Dialog Form) libraries.
When I import the JQueryUI library, I see a strange behavior on the EasyUI Datagrid Header Resize feature. If I try to manually resize the header, only the header cell is resized (the data cells for this column are not resized).

Note that the double click on the header cells separation works and will auto resize the column on the preferred size. The problem occurs when you try to resize by click and slide (manually defining the size of the column).

If I do not import JQueryUI library, then I confirm the resize columns feature of the datagrid is working fine. So I am guessing there must be a kind of conflict between both libraries, but I am not sure on how I could solve this issue.

To reproduce, it is easy, you just need to include the different libraries and create a datagrid.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/default/easyui.css">  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/themes/icon.css">  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/demo/demo.css">
```

```
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.jeasyui.com/easyui/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>  
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<table id="dg" title="My Users" class="easyui-datagrid" style="width:700px;height:250px">
```

...

I created a small jsfiddle project to illustrate the issue, see the http://jsfiddle.net/melane/vmDP8/

You can see for yourself that the header cell size changes is not applied on the data cells.
Do you know how I could fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In fact, I got the answer from the developer of EasyUI framework, it is simply not possible to fix this incompatibility between both framework. So instead, I used the dialog box from EasyUI, and got rid of the dependence of the JQuery-UI framework :

```
<div id="dialog" class="easyui-dialog" title="Action" style="width:317px;height:260px" data-options="
    modal:true,
    closed:true,
    buttons:[{
      text:'Cancel',
      iconCls:'icon-cancel',
      handler:function(){
          $('#dialog').dialog('close');
      }
    }]
">
```

This is illustrated on http://jsfiddle.net/vmDP8/11/ for those interested